# I didn't program my while loop correctly

Tags: c++

```
 printf("What do you do?\n1. Walk Away.\n2. Jump.\n3. Open Door.\n\n");
 scanf("%d",&Choice);
 printf("\n\n\n");
 while(4<=Choice,Choice<=0);
 {
     printf("That is not a choice.\n");
     printf("What do you do?\n1. Walk Away.\n2. Jump.\n3. Open Door.\n\n");
     scanf("%d",&Choice);
     printf("\n\n\n");
 }
```

So this is my program. It works but what I want it to do is to repeat until an answer of 1, 2, or 3 is put in. But no matter what the answer is it has it go through the while loop then continue regardless of the next choice. (Also, I did declare "Choice"; I just didn't want to show the whole program.)

Comment: @jeffamaphone The two expressions are mutually exclusive; he's looking for `||` which is logical OR.

Comment: Oh, yeah.  It's also written awkwardly.

Comment: How do you write the little double line thing?

Comment: @TheAwesomElf It's two pipe characters next to each other

Comment: @TheAwesomElf It's shift and then the button above the enter key that also has the backslash

Comment: Why using `printf` `scanf` when tagged C++?

Answer (score 6):

There are two problems in your code. Your while-loop expression is incorrect. The comma does not do what you think it does: in C/C++, the comma executes the left-hand expression and evaluates to the right-hand expression, meaning that in your case you are only checking the second condition. You probably want:

```
 while(4<=Choice || Choice<=0)
```

The `||` is the OR operator, which returns true if either of the expressions around it are true.

Secondarily, there is a misplaced semicolon at the end of the while loop:

```
while(4<=Choice,Choice<=0); //<-- this should not be here
```

This marks the end of the loop, meaning that your code is parsed as:

```
while(4<=Choice,Choice<=0); //loop body is empty

{
    //and we have a random unnamed block following it
}
```

Remove the semicolon and your while loop should execute correctly.

Answer (score 3):

C and C++ have a comma operator, which has the lowest precedence of all operators.  It evaluates the left operand and throws the result away, and then evaluates the right operand.  Thus, your `while` condition is equivalent to:

```
while (Choice <= 0)
```

You also have a bug because there is a semicolon immediately after the condition, which makes for an infinite loop if `Choice` is not strictly positive (because nothing in the loop changes the value of `Choice`).

What you probably intended to write was:

```
while (Choice >= 4 || Choice <= 0)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The comma operator `,` doesn't test both conditions, it simply returns the second of the two. So your `while` loop is the equivalent of:

```
while(Choice<=0) ;
```

and since there's a `;` following the statement, it is in fact an infinite loop if the condition is met. Good thing you didn't enter a choice of -1.