# Desired output after a while loop is not being displayed

Tags: c++, while-loop

The sum of numbers isn't being displayed. Meanwhile, it's also not showing any compilation error.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int sum = 0, val = 1;
    while (val <= 10);{
        sum += val;
        ++val;
    }

    std::cout << sum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It's simply not running, I'm expecting '55' to be displayed in the terminal, as the program is to add numbers from '1' to '10' both inclusive.

Comment: [Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings) -> https://godbolt.org/z/GbT4fd9M6

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I didn't program my while loop correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794684/i-didnt-program-my-while-loop-correctly)

Comment: Related: [Palindrome numbers get out 6 numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46735509/c-palindrome-numbers-get-out-6-numbers/46735662#46735662) **|** [Can GCC accurately catch useless conditionals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851162/can-gcc-accurately-catch-useless-conditionals) **|** [Why is the code inside a while loop body not being executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29760769/c-while-loops/29760798#29760798)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added a semicolon (`;`) after `while`. Remove it and it works fine.